# three.js share a geometry for lines and particles

Tags: three.js

I would like to use one geometry object for some fancy particle animation and display lines between those particles.

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, particleMaterial);
line = new THREE.Line(geometry, lineMaterial, THREE.LinePieces);
```

Somehow the Line Object is not rendered in the scene, but the particles show up.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pk85y/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `WebGLRenderer` you can't share geometry in some specific situations. Best option is to do `geometry.clone()`.

Here's the jsfiddle fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Pk85y/3/