# Why are my three.js lines so expensive?

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
function drawEdge(source, target) {
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        opacity: 1,
        linewidth: 0.5
    });

    var tmp_geo = new THREE.Geometry();
    tmp_geo.vertices.push(source.data.draw_object.position);
    tmp_geo.vertices.push(target.data.draw_object.position);

    line = new THREE.Line(tmp_geo, material, THREE.LinePieces);
    line.scale.x = line.scale.y = line.scale.z = 1;
    line.originalScale = 1;

    geometries.push(tmp_geo);

    scene.add(line);
}
```

I call this about 2,000 times on 800 points...I tried "caching" where I put the `new THREE.LineBasicMaterial` outside the function but that didn't seem to help.

I thought having the spheres would be the bottleneck and I'd have to move to a particle system but the lines are killing my performance

Comment: Hoe many draw calls are reported when you type `renderer.info` into the console? Can you rewrite your code to add just a single line to the scene having many `LinePieces`?

Comment: calls: 2835 faces: 8064 points: 0 vertices: 24192

Comment: Could you do a single geometry with all the lines? This example shows how to do it: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_sphere.html

Comment: yeah it was all the geometry causing slowdown, not the lines. With that example I'm not sure how to point @ source & target. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489228/three-js-share-a-geometry-for-lines-and-particles there's a particlesystem with lines and one geometry, but as far as I can tell the line is just automatically going to the next vertex in the array

Comment: i used geometry.merge() after adding all my geometry, and drew one line through it. i'm back up to 120fps now. thanks.